# How to name configurable URLs in application config file?

Tags: java, configuration, network-programming, configuration-files

Let's say I have an application which communicates with several other applications (a microservice, if you wish) or systems. Of course, addresses of those other applications or systems should be provided in runtime or in a configuration file.

Some of the other applications or and systems, use HTTP, some are brokers or other custom protocol ones. Now I have issues how to declare that in the configuration file.

For example, REST API's should have the scheme (http/https), host and port, other need only the host and the port. Databases need host, port and database path (the rest after the `jdbc:` part of the URL). How to names those variables in the configuration file so the user configuring them can easily deduct what are they and should they enter the scheme at the start or not and what is expected from them and keep it consistent? Sometimes I confuse myself. I can find names for separate parts of the URL, but not names for certain grouped parts for one.

Examples:

```
api1.host = http://example.com # error, this is the first part of the URL, before the path is appended
api2.url = http://example.com/api # error, I needed the part without the /api
broker.host = 192.168.2.2 # error, the user forgot the port
```

How to avoid this situations and be consistent?

A possible solution, albeit ugly is:

```
api1.SchemeHostPort = ...
db.HostPortPath = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you won't find a foolproof method (and if you do, a more resourceful fool will come along). However, I think there are a few things you can do to help.

1. As you suggested in your question, use configuration entries the form `<name>.<type> = <value>`, or alternatively `<type>.<name> = <value>`.
2. If possible, gather all such variables together and precede them with a comment block that explains what kind of `<value>` should be used for each `<type>`.
3. When the value of a configuration variable is retrieved (typically at start-up), your application should carry out some validation checks on the value, and report an error and die if the validation checks fail.

Comment: I giggled at the resourceful fool sentence. OK, let's see if something else comes up, I was just getting paranoid am I the only one with such a problem.